# Encoding the same values in different columns with same integer in python

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn

I have a data frame with true/false values stored in string format. Some values are null in the data frame.

I need to encode this data such that TRUE/FALSE/null values are encoded with the same integer in every column.

Input:

```
col1 col2 col3
True True False
True True True
null null True
```

I am using:

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Output:

```
2 1 0
2 1 1
1 0 1
```

But I want the output as:

```
2 2 0
2 2 2
1 1 2
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me working create one column `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.stack(dropna=False).to_frame().apply(le.fit_transform)[0].unstack()
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     0
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     1
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `'True'` instead `True`, because:

> I have a data frame with true/false values stored in string format.

If `null` are missing values:

```
df = df.replace({'True':2, 'False':1, np.nan:0})
```

If `null` are strings `null`:

```
df = df.replace({'True':2, 'False':1, 'null':0})

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     2     2     1
1     2     2     2
2     0     0     2
```

Comment: @jazrael df.replace works well for boolean values since there are 3 possible values. Lets say if each column had 100 different values possible. How to encode in such situations where I need same integer encoding for same value?

Comment: @AkshayBharadwaj - Then use first solution.